# writing to a text file in C using fprintf()

Tags: c, multithreading, fopen, printf

I am working with a program to write the summation of 1-500 and 500-1000 using two separate threads.  I need the output to be written in to a text file which is created by the program itself.  When I run the program it creates the file according to the given name, but I am not getting the output as needed.  It only writes one single line to the text file.  That is the summation of 500-1000.  But when I get the output using console it shows the answer as needed. How to overcome this problem.  Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 1000
#define THREADS 2

void *slave(void *myid);

/* shared data */
int data[ARRAYSIZE];    /* Array of numbers to sum */
int sum = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;/* mutually exclusive lock variable */
int wsize;              /* size of work for each thread */
int fd1;
int fd2;
FILE * fp;
char name[20];

/* end of shared data */

void *slave(void *myid)
{

    int i,low,high,myresult=0;

    low = (int) myid * wsize;
    high = low + wsize;

    for(i=low;i<high;i++)
        myresult += data[i];
        /*printf("I am thread:%d low=%d high=%d myresult=%d \n",
        (int)myid, low,high,myresult);*/
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    sum += myresult; /* add partial sum to local sum */

    fp = fopen (name, "w+");
    //printf("the sum from %d to %d is %d",low,i,myresult);
    fprintf(fp,"the sum from %d to %d is %d\n",low,i,myresult);
    printf("the sum from %d to %d is %d\n",low,i,myresult);
    fclose(fp);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return;
}
main()
{
    int i;
    pthread_t tid[THREADS];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL); /* initialize mutex */
    wsize = ARRAYSIZE/THREADS; /* wsize must be an integer */

    for (i=0;i<ARRAYSIZE;i++) /* initialize data[] */
        data[i] = i+1;

    printf("Enter file name : \n");
    scanf("%s",name);
    //printf("Name = %s",name);
    fd1=creat(name,0666);
    close(fd1);

    for (i=0;i<THREADS;i++) /* create threads */
        if (pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,slave,(void *)i) != 0)
            perror("Pthread_create fails");

    for (i=0;i<THREADS;i++){ /* join threads */
        if (pthread_join(tid[i],NULL) != 0){
            perror("Pthread_join fails");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are opening the same file two times, one on each thread. They are overwriting each other's job.

To solve this you can:

1. Use the `a+` mode on `fopen()` to append the new line to end of the existing file, or;
2. Open the file in `main()` and the threads will only `fprintf()` to it.